# Deserialization of xml with attribute AND value

Tags: java, xml, xml-deserialization

i have little bit trouble with deserialization of XML. I am only able to deserialize this xml by:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
List<Object> field;
```

This is my xml:

```
   <Response>
       <user>
          <field attribute="x"></field>
          <field attribute="y">false</field>
          <field attribute="z">string</field>
       </user>
       <user>
          <field attribute="x"></field>
          <field attribute="y">false</field>
          <field attribute="z">string</field>
       </user>
   </Response>
```

Problem is, that i want to replace `Object` in `List<Object> field;` with some specific class so i could access `attribute` and the value in `field`.

With `Object`, i am able to create something like this:

```
user='[{attribute=x}, {attribute=y, =false}, {name=z, =string}]
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer. I created new class that contains this elements:

```
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "attribute")
        String attribute;

        @JacksonXmlText
        String value;
```

And replace the `Object` with this new class.